# what does "method1().method2().method3()" mean in java?

Tags: java, methods

I know some basics of java language.
But I don't know some statements like this:

```
method1().method2().method3()
```

Two or three methods separated whit dots operator! I cannot understand it.

What does it mean? How can I use them? Do they process from left to right or reverse?
Does they return special values or not?
How can I understand I should some methods separate whit dot?
How can I create methods like this?

Comment: It "means nothing" but is often referred to as [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) (which usually implies each return object is the same, although it need not be); variations can be used for the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: This is heavy used in the `Builder` pattern: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/the-builder-pattern-in-practice.html

Answer (score 7):

I will gave you a little example.

```
method1().method2().method3();

getYear().toString().trim();
```

first execute get year() which returns a Integer:

```
1995.toString().trim();
```

secound execute toString() method of integer class which returns an string:

```
"1995".trim();
```

at least the compiler would execute trim() method of string class.

the first method return a number then you use toString() method on this number and format it to a string. this will return a string and then you can use the trim() method of string class to trim() the string. you are executed the next method after you get the return from the method in front of.

Answer (score 3):

That is chaining of method calls. THe object returned by `method1()` will call `method2()`
As an example,

```
public static String methodToReturnString() {
    return "someString";
}
```

You call this using `String subString =  methodToReturnString().toLowerCase().substring(3);` 
This returns a `String` `estring`.

This is similar to the code as follows.

```
String s1 = methodToReturnString();
String s2 = s1.toLowerCase();
String s3 = s2.substring(3);
System.out.println(s3);
```

As for generating this `s3` variable, we needed to store the return values of method in some variables which is not needed. Using method chaining, we have avoided variables `s1`, `s2` here.

Answer (score 1):

method1 returns object, which has method2 and then you can call method2, which returns object that has method3 and you call it.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement will be interpreted as follows:

1. Invoke `method1()`. The return value will be some object.
2. Invoke `method2()` on the object returned by `method1()`. This method too must have a return value.
3. Invoke `method3()` on the object returned by `method2()`.

You can rewrite this as:

```
SomeType value1 = method1();
SomeOtherType value2 = value1.method2();
value2.method3();
```

Answer (score 0):

See... For example we might have

```
String s= "abcde";
String str =  s.trim().subString(2); 

1 --> trim() is called on "s".
2 --> subString() is called on the result of s.trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

Method1 returns object1, which has method2 which returns object2, which has method3.

**Object1 and object2 and current object can be identical, which is used in builder pattern.**

Something like:

```
Student {
    Semester lastFinishedSemester();
}

Semester {
    Courses registeredCourses();
}

Courses {
    void printCoursesAndGrades();
}
```

now if you are in one of `student` methods, you can call:

```
lastFinishedSemester().registeredCourses().printCoursesAndGrades();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.method1().method2().method3()
```

equals to

```
( ( obj.method1() ).method2() ).method3()
```

Important:

`method1()` must return an object that has `method2()`
`method2()` must return an object that has `method3()`

Source: Yosi Hendarsjah's answer in https://coderanch.com/t/398558/java/method-chaining